How to block Facebook crawl *.fbsv.net servers?
I'm running a PHP VBulletin forum and it's spammed by extremely many requests from Facebook crawl servers with hostnames like:

fwdproxy-cco-031.fbsv.net
fwdproxy-prn-050.fbsv.net

Does anyone know a set of iptables commands to block them entirely?

Firewall rules work best when you provide IP-address ranges and not host names. So investigate which ranges are used by Facebook and block those in your firewall.
Facebook suggests suggests among others the following command to determine which IP-address ranges are currently in use:
whois -h whois.radb.net -- '-i origin AS32934' | grep ^route  


Thank you! That's a good start, I just have to write a little script tomorrow that actually generates iptables commands from that whois command.
